# mysql error operand should have 1 columns stored procedure

Tags: mysql, variables, stored-procedures

i try to create stored procedure but when i try my code it isnt work 
my troubel is on @tgl when i execute the SP why it error operand should have 1 column

```
BEGIN

SET @book = booking_id;



set @tgl = concat(("d"),('SELECT RIGHT(booking_checkin ,2) as date FROM pt_bookings WHERE booking_id = ',@book));

set @month =concat('SELECT mid(booking_checkin ,6,2) as month FROM pt_bookings WHERE booking_id = ',@book);

set @year = concat('SELECT IF(left(booking_checkin ,4)  = "2019", "0", "1") as year FROM pt_bookings WHERE booking_id = ',@book);


PREPARE stmt FROM @year;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

PREPARE stmt FROM @month;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

PREPARE stmt FROM @tgl;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;


END
```

my expetation for @tgl is number + d (22d)

Comment: What would you expect @tgl  SQL statement to look like? -  your doesn't appear to make sense and wouldn't generate a valid sql statement;

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, the error you got is caused by this:

set @tgl = concat(("d"),('SELECT... ', @book));

You can concatenate a list of strings, but not a list of tuples. You

But if I may make some suggestions, you have other issues with this procedure. I think you're making it harder than it needs to be.

You don't need to use prepared statements for any of these. You can just run them as three queries, and use the procedure argument directly in the query. But make the procedure argument name distinct from the column name you're querying, or else the query will be ambiguous.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE WhateverYourProcNameIs(IN in_booking_d INT)
BEGIN

  SELECT RIGHT(booking_checkin ,2) as date 
  FROM pt_bookings WHERE booking_id = in_booking_id;

  SELECT mid(booking_checkin ,6,2) as month 
  FROM pt_bookings WHERE booking_id = in_booking_id;

  SELECT IF(left(booking_checkin ,4)  = '2019', '0', '1') as year 
  FROM pt_bookings WHERE booking_id = in_booking_id;

END
```

This will generate three query results, which is probably not what you want, because you'll have to write more complex client code to advance to the second and third query result.

I think you probably want one query result with three columns. So you could write this in the following way:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE WhateverYourProcNameIs(IN in_booking_d INT)
BEGIN

  SELECT RIGHT(booking_checkin ,2) as date, 
         MID(booking_checkin ,6,2) as month, 
         IF(LEFT(booking_checkin ,4)  = '2019', '0', '1') as year 
  FROM pt_bookings WHERE booking_id = in_booking_id;

END
```

I would further simplify the code by using builtin functions:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE WhateverYourProcNameIs(IN in_booking_d INT)
BEGIN

  SELECT DAY(booking_checkin) as date, 
         MONTH(booking_checkin) as month, 
         YEAR(booking_checkin) as year 
  FROM pt_bookings WHERE booking_id = in_booking_id;

END
```

I don't know what you're doing with the expression converting 2019 to 0 and any other year to 1. But that seems like a bad idea. So 2018 and 2020 and 2021 and 2022 and 2023 and any subsequent year forever are all just '1'? That doesn't make sense.

Oh, I am guessing the requirement is "return 0 for the *current year*, and 1 for *next year*" but you misunderstood that to be *fixed* for 2019. I'm sure they meant 0 for the current year in whatever year they call the procedure. I.e. next year, 2020 should return 0 and 2021 should return 1. You should ask for more complete requirements.